# Linq to SQL: how to refresh table in DbContext inserted by trigger during save

Tags: linq-to-sql, triggers

I have a Issue entity and when a new Issue is created and saved in the database it fires a trigger to insert to a status_history table. This status_history has a FK on Issue.issue_id.  In my UI, there's a data grid that display this status_history.  The bug I am trying to fix is that when a new Issue is saved, the trigger is fired but the status_history is not getting refreshed and so the new record inserted by the trigger is not showing up in the data grid.  The application is using Linq to SQL.  Is there a way to refresh the status_history entity and also the issue.status_histories?  I tried calling Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, newIssue) but the status_histories still have a 0 count and the status_history entity still have the same count as before the save.

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly.

The `DataContext` has gone "stale" because the updates trough the trigger bypass the change tracking mechanisme of the `DataContext` / Linq-2-sql.

Therefore you need to create a new `datacontext` after the update. This will re-retrieve the fresh data and it will show again.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the newIssue object would not help, it just updates the queried object and the values of that object.

But you can refresh the table. 
Let's say you have a data context instance called mDB and your table is called Issue:

**mDB.Refresh**(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, **mDB.Issues**)